# How do I open a new form with a button, using C++ Builder?

Tags: c++builder

I have a program with Form1 and Form2. How can I open form2 from form1 clicking a button?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just a little more info

having this in your Project.cpp: Application->CreateForm(__classid(TForm2), &Form2); means that the form will be created when you start your application.

if you want to create the form your self when clicking the button do the following

```
TForm2 *Form = new TForm2( this );
Form->ShowModal();
```

if for instance you need to use a custom constructor you can also create a new form passing in any values you need. for example

```
TForm2 *Form = new TForm2( this, "My New Form" , Now() );
Form->ShowModal();
```

The above method besides setting the owner of the form passes in a string and a TDateTime you could then uses them in your forms constructor to do some stuff.

remember if you create these forms your self you will need to delete them.

to allow other buttons or controls also access you form you need to do the following

in the private section of the header add the following

```
TForm2 *Form;
```

now back in the cpp you will need to create teh form before you can use it, this changes slightly from the earlier one

```
Form = new TForm2( this );
Form->ShowModal();
```

but now if you want to access the form to say update the caption you can simply do

```
Form->Caption = "Changed Caption";
```

the caption on the form will now be changed

Comment: I hope this won't cause a memory leak since the TForm2 *Form pointer will go out of scope as soon as the button's event ends.

Comment: Yes the first way would cause a memory leak. As I said if you create these forms your self you will need to delete them. The last option the form is declared in the header so you only need to create it once and can delete it later for example when closing the form hosting the button

Comment: So if the form is closed with an X button, is it automatically deleted?

Comment: If you delete it yourself in the destructor or it’s created using an auto_ptr

Answer (score 5):

Borland what? Delphi? C++ Builder?

For Delphi:
Ensure that Delphi created an instance of `Form2` in Project.dpr: `Application.CreateForm(TForm2, Form2);`
Then add the `Form2` unit name to one of the `uses` clauses in the `Form1` unit, then you can use `Form2.Show;` or `Form2.ShowModal;`.

For C++:
Ensure that C++ Builder created an instance of `Form2` in Project.cpp: `Application->CreateForm(__classid(TForm2), &Form2);`
Then add an `#include` statement for the .hpp file of the `Form2` unit to the .cpp file of the `Form1` unit, then you can use `Form2->Show();` or `Form2->ShowModal();`.