# TObject.Show() not reachable on C++ Builder

Tags: c++, show, c++builder

I'm currently starting to learn how to use **C++ Builder**. However, I'm stuck on doing something basic, which is to open a window when I click on an element of the menu. I'm ok with the event management, but when I try to display it with the method **Show()**, it's written when compiling that "the method is not reachable" (I have it in french so I'm not sure about the exact translation). I've tried it different ways, also with the popup element, but I always get this message. Here is the short code that I use to display the window :

```
TFrame1 * NewPageFormer = new TFrame1(this);
NewPageFormer->Show();

delete NewPageFormer;
NewPageFormer = NULL;
```

Do you have any idea where the problem comes from?

Thank you

Comment: I'm not familiar with c++ Builder but can you show the Class TFrame1? Maybe the Method `Show` is private...

Comment: For now, the Class TFrame1 does nothing but inheriting from TFrame, which is the class for Windows in C++ Builder. TFrame itself inherits the method Show() from TObject. The error seems like Show() is private instead of protected, but of course it doesn't make any sense, and it's public according to the doc. Thank you

Comment: `TObject` does not have a `Show()` method.  It is inherited from `TControl` instead, which is indeed **public** in `TControl`.  `TCustomForm` also declares its own `Show()` method that hides the `TControl` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with:

```
TForm1 * NewPageFormer = new TForm1(this);
NewPageFormer->Show();
```

What you should `Show()` is a `TForm` (e.g. take a look at [How do I open a new form with a button, using C++ Builder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10794869/how-do-i-open-a-new-form-with-a-button-using-c-builder)).

Frames are combinations of components placed on a form-like object, which are considered a cohesive whole.

A frame ([`TFrame`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Using_and_Modifying_Frames)), like a form, is a container for other components. It uses the same ownership mechanism as forms for automatic instantiation and destruction of the components on it, and the same parent-child relationships for synchronization of component properties.

However **a frame is more like a customized component than a form**, so you cannot directly call the `Show()` method of a frame.

Comment: Thank you, I was using the wrong object, it works with a TForm. Have a nice day.

Comment: Yes, you should be calling `Show()` on a `TForm` instead of a `TFrame`. However, that in of itself would not have caused the error. `TFrame` is a `TControl` descendant (just like `TForm` is), and `TControl` has a **public** `Show()` method that `TFrame` inherits (and `TCustomForm` hides).